# Does C# provide "correct" const for reference type objects?

Tags: c#

New to C#. After reading MS programming guide and several online tutorials, I found out that member of `readonly` reference type object (`class`) can be changed (and `const` can be applied to build-in types):

`public readonly Point Origin = new Point { X = 0, Y = 0 };`
`Origin.X = 7; // compiles and works !!`

Compared to C++ const correctness, C# implementation of const seems like a huge flaw in the language design. I am missing something ? Is there any other way to guarantee constant correctness of reference type objects ?

Comment: In `readonly Point Origin` it's `Origin` which is `readonly`, not `Origin.X`. There is no such thing as "deep const" in the current .NET; however it's going to be added in the upcoming versions. You can already see work in progress [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Point is an object that exposes public properties - X and Y. if you want to prevent them from being changed, they should be declared as `const` in the `Point` class.

Comment: Different languages are different?

Comment: @Vlad Is that true? New version will have such feature?

Comment: @Sriram: spreading some rumours: http://wesnerm.blogs.com/net_undocumented/2013/12/immutable-isolated-types-highly-likely-in-future-c.html

Comment: Why not just make the an immutable class in the first place?

Comment: Just make reference type immutable (e.g., throw away public property setters)

Comment: What "flaw" - do you mean lack of some sort of `readonly_cast` (to match [const_cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz6at95h.aspx) :)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Compared to C++ const correctness, C# implementation of const seems like a huge flaw in the language design.

It is not. Actually, the opposite is true.

> Is there any other way to guarantee constant correctness of reference type objects ?

So-called "const correctness" in C/C++ is a misnomer.

Suppose I have a program with zero undefined behaviour in it. And suppose I have a reference to `foo` with field `bar`, and I pass it via const reference to method `blah`. Do I have any **guarantee** that in this fully-defined program when `blah` returns, `foo.bar` is unchanged, regardless of what `blah` does?  Absolutely not!  Suppose I am implementing method `blah` and I have a const reference to the `foo`.  Do I have any **guarantee** that throughout the operation of `blah`, `bar` will not be observed to change?  Absolutely not!

The invariant that I want is "this thing will not be observed to change"; what I get in C++ is "you're not allowed to change this thing via this reference". The useful invariant implied by so-called "const correctness" that I would like to have is not actually guaranteed.

By contrast in C# a constant field is something you can rely on; that thing is going to stay the same no matter how many times you look at it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it may seem wrong or not, depending on your criteria/requirements.

This:

```
public readonly SomeClass Name = new SomeClass();
...
Name.SomeProperty = NewValue;
```

will indeed work, because the `readonly` property only applies to the field named `Name`  (of type `SomeClass`).

It does not in any way whatsoever propagate into the object you store in that field. In other words, you can change properties and fields in that object.

What you **can't** do, is this:

```
Name = new SomeClass(); // or some other reference to a SomeClass
```

*(unless you use Reflection, but that is another story)*

Now, you may want to have `const` mean "not only is this field `const`, but I can also only store a `const` *type* in this field", but sadly that is not possible.

Additionally, you (and I) may want some way to say "not only is this field *const*, but the type I chose to store in it must be immutable as well", but unfortunately there is no (current) way to get the compiler to verify this bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a difference in the paradigm of what a `const` means.  The following code won't work:

```
Origin = new Point();
```

Anywhere else in the code other than instantiation.

Within the definition of the `Point` object to make `X` and `Y` both `const` you would need to define them as such:

```
public class Point
{
    const int X = 0;
    const int Y = 0;
}
```

Now in your example, neither `X` nor `Y` are assignable.  You only perceive this as a flaw in the language because of your C++ background.  For those who have been using C# for a while, this comes perfectly natural.

Answer (score 1):

`readonly` only means that the ***value*** of the field cannot be changed outside of constructors.

The value of the reference type is the reference. So what cannot be changed is "which" object the field references. That object instance might be mutated a lot through instance methods, properties and fields (not `readonly`) that the object may have.

On the other hand, the "value" of a value type (`struct`) is different. However, many people discourage structs that can be mutated in any way, and in case their advice is followed, this becomes less important.

Consider making the `Point` type immutable. If `X` and `Y` are fields, make them `readonly` or convert them into `get`-only properties. If they are properties, make them `get`-only (`set` accessor absent or `private`).